# Is it possible to determine your average question and answer scores?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'd like to determine the average number of upvotes and downvotes for all my questions and answers. Are there any database commands to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Some](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/406369/what-is-my-average-question-score) of [these](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/488747/what-is-my-average-answer-score) queries already exist. However, I made a slightly more at-a-glance version that captures average score, as well as average upvotes and downvotes for both questions and answers.

### Disclaimers

The usual SEDE disclaimers apply here:

- It only updates once a week (usually Sunday morning, depending on your timezone), so it won't include any questions or answers posted in the last few days
- Deleted questions and answers are not included

### [The results](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/488789/my-post-averages)

Here are mine:

[image]

Average question score is 15.63, with an average of 15.81 upvotes and 0.19 downvotes per question.

Average answer score is 15.44, with an average of 15.48 upvotes and 0.04 downvotes per answer.

Here's yours:

[image]

Average question score is 10.76, with an average of 11.66 upvotes and 0.9 downvotes per question.

Average answer score is 6.84, with an average of 6.9 upvotes and 0.07 downvotes per answer.

Comment: Thanks. Is the site-wide average known?

Comment: @RogueJedi I don't know, but it would be relatively easy to modify these queries to find it; just remove the INNER JOIN condition

Comment: @RogueJedi If you're curious, site-wide average question score is 9.33, and average answer score is 7.92

Comment: Ooh. Mine is 16.1 and 9.9. Nice

Comment: +1. I believe there are also tag-specific queries which rank all users by their average answer score in e.g. the Harry Potter tag?

Comment: Neat! One little quibble - the column in the results of your average question score query is still named AverageAnswerScore. That confused me for a moment.

Comment: @recognizer Not my query, so I take no responsibility. But hopefully my new query is a little bit more intuitive

Comment: both columns for ``upvotes`` and ``downvotes`` are named ``upvotes``. just for information...

Comment: @Armin [Whoops](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/1c/38/5f/1c385fbe3bbf2d3143f31105c3693d68.jpg); thanks for the catch

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Nice one-liner to paste into the Data Explorer:

```
SELECT AVG(Score) AS [Average Score] FROM Posts WHERE OwnerUserId = ##UserId:int##
```

Provides an average score across all posts. If you want to filter to post types, you'll need to add another constraint.

*N.B. Will always output an integer, because of integer division. Can be worked around, if necessary.*

Comment: Worth noting that this will always output an integer

Comment: @JasonBaker Aye, which I quite like because post scores are also integers.